# Outlook table formula

Tags: microsoft-outlook

For project work, we capture employee's estimated time spent on certain things via Outlook.

I'd like to have a table in Outlook formatted to SUM the total numbers in the column and check if it equals 100%.

Is it possible to insert a function in Outlook? I checked out some of the formulas, but they seemed static, versus dynamic.

Comment: @EricF I realized I was trying to insert an Equation and not a Formula (missed it on the Layout tab). Left a comment/answer below for what is working for me now.

Comment: Great job then and thanks for sharing your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

1. Create a table
2. Click in the field you want the total/formula to be in
3. Click "LAYOUT" on the ribbon
4. Select "Formula" in the upper right corner
5. Enter the desired formula (in my case, it was `=SUM(ABOVE)`)
6. Select the desired Number format (in my case, percentage)

Done! However this isn't dynamic/auto refreshed, so if you make adjustments to the table and need to recalculate, you can do the following:

1. Highlight/double-click the formula field
2. Right-click and select "Update Field"
3. The formula should now be refreshed/updated

If anyone knows how to not have to manually refresh the formula, I would love to know how to do that!